# FourSum in C++ - Optimization

Tags: c++, optimization

I am trying to make a C++ program of the FourSum problem i.e. Does there exist a sum of four different numbers that sum to zero. 
"i + j + k + l = 0" "-2 + -1 + 3 + 0 = 0"
I can get it to work, but the running time is around 10-15 times slower than the java implementation (both are naive approaches, so basically just four for loops). I know it is possible to use BinarySearch for the last loop, provided you sort the array. But it was my understanding that generally C++ should perform better and run faster than Java and certainly also Python. So how do I do that?
Any or all suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    string line;
    int N;
    ifstream myfile ("ints/ints-400-1.txt");

    getline(myfile,line);
    stringstream into(line);

    into >> N;
    std::vector<long long> vals (N); 

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
    int i = 0;

    while ( getline(myfile,line) ) {
             vals[i] = stoll( line );
             ++i;
        }

        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

    for (int i = 0; i != vals.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j != vals.size(); j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k != vals.size(); k++) {
                for (int l = k + 1; l != vals.size(); l++) {
                    if (vals[i] + vals[j] + vals[k] +vals[l] == 0) {
                    cout << "true";
                    }                        
                }
            }
        }
    }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: sounds like an online coding contest. Such contest usually force you to think first and the implement a not so obvious solution while the brute force will timeout. Four loops is definitely not the way to go. What comes to my mind is first sort the numbers and then start from both ends and try to exclude combinations that you dont have to compare explicitly. Maybe thats completely off.... i dont know. Anyhow for code reviews there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it was really just a blind guess. The idea is that if you have to find 2 numbers that add to zero you just need two pointers one starting at the front and one at the end of a sorted list and then move them inwards to find a match. Finding a sum of 4 can only be just a little bit more complicated ;)

Comment: ..well apply this idea twice and you already have something that is better than four loops (but still not optimal)

Comment: for java vs c++ vs python it depends. c++ gives you more control, but its up to you to make use of it. A poor c++ algorithm can be beaten easily by a better algorithm written in any language

Comment: What compiler flags are you setting for the compile? If you are just doing **g++ program.cpp** then you are likely not going to get great performance compared to optimization levels like **g++ -O3 program.cpp**

Comment: yeah i think that is the problem right now. as you say - more freedom (in my case) to use inefficient code. The first part runs fine, the loading of the file and creation of array.

Comment: Just use "g++ foursum.cpp". Can you recommend a source on compilers maybe?

Comment: @patemotter That certainly helped alot. From 10 seconds to 0.77. Thanks for that.

Comment: Use linux perf tool (in case it is linux env), you can look at some examples at http://techunravel.blogspot.in/2018/03/how-to-use-linux-perf-tool-and-save.html to check if your code has any obvious performance issues